# Ionic Framework: StaticInjectionError [{provide:PlatformLocation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, runtime-error

When running the "ionic serve" command, my app is building just fine and it opens in the browser but I get an error in the browser stating:

> StaticInjectionError[{provide:PlatformLocation, useClass:BrowserPlatformLocation}]: 'deps' required

I looked this error up online but found none with the "provide:PlatformLocation" bit of the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am lost right now.

Comment: It would seem that you are missing some dependencies. Would you mind sharing your code? I assume this is your app module bit

Comment: What page of my code do you want to see? the app.module.ts?